# To display the image using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In the below code i have a image stored in C drive and i want to display that image .I tried but i couldn't solve the issue.Pls help me to solve this.

```
public string strName = "Sample";
        public string strFolder = "Search";
        public string Imgdocname = "Image0529.jpg";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileExt = ".jpg";

            if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".jpg")
            {

                docimg.ImageUrl = "~/" + strName + "/" + strFolder + "/" + Imgdocname;
                docimg.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                docimg.ImageUrl = "~/doc/Documents/image.jpeg";
                docimg.Visible = true;
            }   }



<div ID="imgContainer" runat="server" style="width: 700px; height: 300px;  overflow:auto; border: solid 1px black;
                    padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;" >
<asp:Image ID="docimg" runat="server" />

          </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a subfolders under your website root that are named `/doc/` and `/doc/Documents/`?

Comment: @David Tansey  yes i have sub folders it is in C drive

Comment: strName, strFolder and Imgdocname (all three) are available to you then why don't you make it as a direct URL like docimg.Imageurl = "C:\\Sample\\Search\\Image0529.jpg" or docimg.Imageurl = ".\\Sample\\Search\\Image0529.jpg" (Use "\\" instead of "/"). Second thing, you are using docimg.Visible = true in both the sections of IF part. So you can pull this line out of code and at client side make it visible because in either conidtion so are showing this.

Comment: @Amnesh Goel The Above is an example.But in my case i pass that as parameter .For ur understanding i mention it.

Comment: @user3580909 Means you are generating this path at runtime. Event that is fine, that should not be a problem. Why don't you assign it like docimg.Imageurl = path; //in path you can set that path. It could be your website directory path or anything else.

Comment: What are you doing ???? are you trying to show an image hosted on c??? I'm a little bit confused ........also from where is come fileExt and which type of if statement are you doing......seems a little bit wrong this code.Let us excatly which is your goal.

Comment: @makemoney2010 Actually the image format is checking using if condition works well My aim is to display image from C drive.

Comment: Then what is the problem in giving the path if you know that? Or what problem/ error is coming? Would you like to share that error?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are inserting the ImageURL property in the back-end by using the tilde ~ sign... but you're actually putting it into the property instead.

The way the tilde works, is that the .ASPX code is parsed by the back-end before it is sent to the browser, and when the parser encounters the "~" sign, it replaces it with the relative path of the application... however, that only happens on the ASPX Parser. Not the back-end code...

so in the end, i bet that if you look at the source of your page in your web browser, you get something like this:

```
<img src="~/files/images/filename.jpg" />
```

instead of what you really want which is:

```
<img src="../files/images/filename.jpg" />
```

the way around that is by doing this in your back-end code:

```
if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".jpg")
            {

                docimg.ImageUrl = Request.MapPath("~/" + strName + "/" + strFolder + "/" + Imgdocname);
                docimg.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                docimg.ImageUrl = Request.MapPath("~/doc/Documents/image.jpeg");
                docimg.Visible = true;
            }
```

this will actually resolve the tilde to the actual path needed at your front-end.